# Returning iterator from weak references for mapping and modifying values

Tags: rust, iterator, weak-references, refcell

I'm trying quite complex stuff with Rust where I need the following attributes, and am fighting the compiler.

1. Object which itself lives from start to finish of application, however, where internal maps/vectors could be modified during application lifetime
2. Multiple references to object that can read internal maps/vectors of an object
3. All single threaded
4. Multiple nested iterators which are map/modified in lazy manner to perform fast and complex calculations (see example below)

A small example, which already causes problems:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::sync::Weak;

pub struct Holder {
    array_ref: Weak<RefCell<Vec<isize>>>,
}

impl Holder {
    pub fn new(array_ref: Weak<RefCell<Vec<isize>>>) -> Self {
        Self { array_ref }
    }

    fn get_iterator(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = f64> + '_ {
        self.array_ref
            .upgrade()
            .unwrap()
            .borrow()
            .iter()
            .map(|value| *value as f64 * 2.0)
    }
}
```

`get_iterator` is just one of the implementations of a trait, but even this example already does not work.

The reason for `Weak`/`Rc` is to make sure that multiple places points to object (from point (1)) and other place can modify its internals (`Vec<isize>`).

What is the best way to approach this situation, given that end goal is performance critical?

**EDIT**:
Person suggested using https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Ref.html#method.map

But unfortunately still can't get - if I should also change return type - or maybe the closure function is wrong here

```
fn get_iterator(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item=f64> + '_ {
    let x = self.array_ref.upgrade().unwrap().borrow();
    let map1 = Ref::map(x, |x| &x.iter());
    let map2 = Ref::map(map1, |iter| &iter.map(|y| *y as f64 * 2.0));
    map2
}
```

IDEA say it has wrong return type

```
 the trait `Iterator` is not implemented for `Ref<'_, Map<std::slice::Iter<'_, isize>, [closure@src/bin/main.rs:30:46: 30:65]>>`
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't work because `self.array_ref.upgrade()` creates a local temporary `Arc` value, but the `Ref` only borrows from it.  Obviously, you can't return a value that borrows from a local.

To make this work you need a second structure to own the `Arc`, which can implement `Iterator` *in this case* since the produced items aren't references:

```
pub struct HolderIterator(Arc<RefCell<Vec<isize>>>, usize);

impl Iterator for HolderIterator {
    type Item = f64;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<f64> {
        let r = self.0.borrow().get(self.1)
            .map(|&y| y as f64 * 2.0);
            
        if r.is_some() {
            self.1 += 1;
        }
        
        r
    }
}

// ...

impl Holder {
    // ...

    fn get_iterator<'a>(&'a self) -> Option<impl Iterator<Item=f64>> {
        self.array_ref.upgrade().map(|rc| HolderIterator(rc, 0))
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want the iterator to also weakly-reference the value contained within, you can have it hold a `Weak` instead and upgrade on each `next()` call.  There are performance implications, but this also makes it easier to have `get_iterator()` be able to return an iterator directly instead of an `Option`, and the iterator written so that a failed upgrade means the sequence has ended:

```
pub struct HolderIterator(Weak<RefCell<Vec<isize>>>, usize);

impl Iterator for HolderIterator {
    type Item = f64;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<f64> {
        let r = self.0.upgrade()?
            .borrow()
            .get(self.1)
            .map(|&y| y as f64 * 2.0);
            
        if r.is_some() {
            self.1 += 1;
        }
        
        r
    }
}

// ...

impl Holder {
    // ...

    fn get_iterator<'a>(&'a self) -> impl Iterator<Item=f64> {
        HolderIterator(Weak::clone(&self.array_ref), 0)
    }
}
```

This will make it so that you always get an iterator, but it's empty if the `Weak` is dead.  The `Weak` can also die during iteration, at which point the sequence will abruptly end.